# Bayes Optimal Classification Rule

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, classification

Suppose  that $Y∈ {0,1}$ and $P(Y=1) = 1/2$.  The  distribution  of $X|Y= 0$ is discrete and is specified by $$P(X= 1|Y= 0) = 1/3 $$    $$P(X= 2|Y= 0) = 2/3$$The distribution of $X|Y= 1$ is discrete and is given by $$P(X= 2|Y= 1) = 1/3$$ $$P(X= 3|Y= 1) = 2/3$$

This is all I can find about the Bayes Classifier in my textbook:

[image]

How would I be able to find the Bayes Classifier?

Comment: Whic probability/expression does Bayes decision use?

Answer (score 1):

Bayes classifier chooses the class with maximum posterior probability. Since there are two classes, if $P(Y=1|X=x)\geq1/2$ it means posterior for class $1$ is the maximum one, and we choose it. That is why if $\eta(X)\geq 1/2$, it chooses class $1$.

The formula for the posterior you've shared at the end is correct. You just need to be careful about calling the negative class as $0$ or $-1$, and make sure $X$ values given in class conditional probabilities are correct (e.g. the upper one deals with $X=1,2$ and the lower one deals with $X=2,3$). In the end, you'll have a function that for each $X$ value, a class label is assigned.